# Traverse JSON object/array and delete field of selected objects

Tags: json, jq

I have a bunch of JSON files (fixtures) from which I need to delete a field if the "current" object happens to match a `select` filter.

I'm able to match the desired objects but I'm not sure how to perform the deletion of the field so that the object is modified in-place.

So far this is the closest I've gotten to:

```sh
jq '..|objects|select(.__typename == "MyType") | del(.delete_me)' fixture.json
```

But doesn't seem to work correctly, assignment of the field is straight forward I'm thinking I could probably try and use `path as $paths` and `getpath` to set the "parent" value with the output of `del` but I'm stuck and don't quite fully understand the functions.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For "in-place" deletion of a key, you might find `walk` quite congenial:

```
walk(if type == "object" and .__typename == "MyType" 
     then del(.delete_me) else . end)
```

Comment: Let me give it a try, seems clear enough